# shell sort inverso java

Tags: java, shell

pessoal estou com uma duvida, como fazer shell sort inverso decrescente.

```
private static void shellsort(int v[], int n) {
    int i, j, aux, h = 1;
    do
        h = 3 * h + 1;
    while (h < n);
    do {
        h /= 3;
        for (i = h; i < n; i++) {
            aux = v[i];
            j = i - h;
            while (j >= 0 && aux < v[j]) {
                v[j + h] = v[j];
                j -= h;
            }
            v[j + h] = aux;
        }
    } while (h > 1);
}
```

Comment: Olá, o que tem de errado com o exemplo que aí tens ?

Comment: no exemplo ele faz em ordem crescente, e eu gostaria na ordem decrescente =(                                                                                                                                               Vetor[995]= 99486
Vetor[996]= 99492
Vetor[997]= 99583
Vetor[998]= 99701
Vetor[999]= 99765

Comment: Para mudar de crescente para decrescente basta mudar a condicao `aux < v[j]` para `aux > v[j]`

Answer (score 1):

Boa noite, para mudar de crescente para decrescente no seu código, basta alterar a condição `aux < v[j]` para `aux > v[j]`

por exemplo:

```
private static void shellsort(int v[], int n, boolean crescente) {
    int i, j, aux, h = 1;
    do
        h = 3 * h + 1;
    while (h < n);
    do {
        h /= 3;
        for (i = h; i < n; i++) {
            aux = v[i];
            j = i - h;
            if (crescente) {
                while (j >= 0 && aux < v[j]) {
                    v[j + h] = v[j];
                    j -= h;
                }
            } else {
                while (j >= 0 && aux > v[j]) {
                    v[j + h] = v[j];
                    j -= h;
                }
            }
            v[j + h] = aux;
        }
    } while (h > 1);
}
```